# error when importing android projects into eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, import

currently i have difficulties trying to import the lynda.com android app development with java essential training exercise files into eclipse. I keep getting some java errors like this.Can someone help me out with this problem?
Currently im using

- Android SDK r12
- ADT 12 plugin for eclipse
- JDK 7x64
- JRE 7x64
- LEclipse IDE for Java Developers 3.7 indigo

here's the error:

> The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot
>   find the class file for java.lang.Object. Fix the build path, then try
>   building this project.
>
> The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
>   referenced from required .class files

*(original screenshot below)*
[image]

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=eclipse+the+type+cannot+be+resolve+it+is+indirectly+referenced+from+required+class+files

Answer (score 3):

A little late on this, however after struggling with the issue myself I found a solution to the problem.

1. Right Click on the project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path...
2. In the 'Source' tab, Select the project eg. 'myProject/src' --> Click OK.
3. Right Click on the project --> Android Tools --> Fix Project Properties

That should do it!

Comment: Why would the first two options have any effect? You are doing nothing there.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing your compiler to Java 5 instead of Java 7?
Also make sure that in the project settings that you're using Java 5.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan,

I had the same problem and it was corrected by going to the project preferences(right click project -->preferences).  Then go to "java build path" and click on the libraries tab.  Look for your JRE lib in the list.  In my case the system was unable to find it, but the entry was still there.  Delete this and add a new one by clicking "add library" and select JRE System library.  Then select the default system lib.  Close out of the preferences window and then Right click on your project and go to android tools-->Fix project Properties.  Clean your project and try building again.

Comment: it's project properties and not preferences.

Answer (score 0):

This works

Project > Properties > Android > change the Build Target